# Current active phone call is terminated on receiving Voip Push Notification on iOS 13

Tags: call, voip, ios13, callkit, pushkit

Cellular call running and incoming VoIP push failing cellular call on iOS 13, even if incoming call showing on below method.

```c
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type
```

Showing Incoming call-kit screen when VoIP push received.

```c
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type {

    [self displayIncomingCall:callbackUUIDToken handle:_payLoad.handle hasVideo:([_payLoad.pushType caseInsensitiveCompare:PUSH_TYPE_VIDEO_CALL] == NSOrderedSame)
        withCompletion:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

Disconnecting cellular call, while Face-time and Whatsapp call works as expected.